# Assignment operator in the context of arrays in fortran

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

If I have two arrays, say A and B, and let's say my declarations are:

```
real(kind=8) :: A(1, 10)
real(kind=8), intent(in) :: B(1, 20)
```

where B is an array that I am receiving from somewhere. I have a function F, which needs the data I have stored in B, but B has stored data in packs of 10 (that is, elements 1 to 10 belong to a particular set, 11 to 20 to a different set and so on), so I am using A to store 10 values of B sequentially.

If I call a function by passing A, I am technically passing the address of the first element of the array A right? So if I run a loop:

```
do i = 1, 2
   A(1, 1) = B(1, 10*i - 9)
   call F(A)
end do
```

am I actually asking the function F to read from the element (10*i - 9) in the ith loop? (like 1st element in the first loop, 11th element in the second loop) Of course, this is equivalent to writing

```
do i = 1, 2
   call F(B(1, 10*i - 9))
end do
```

but I wanted to make it absolutely sure that I understand about passing of array pointers via functions and subroutines properly. Please do let me know if there are some blatant errors in whatever I have said here. Thanks

Comment: How is the argument of `F` declared? Either way, "If I call a function by passing A, I am technically passing the address of the first element of the array A right?" is wrong. It's just less wrong in some circumstances.

Comment: Let's say the argument of F is written as

real(kind=8), intent(in) :: B(1, 10)

If I am not wrong, this ensures that the incoming array is of size 10. If you could, can you elaborate on your latter statement?

Comment: I see; my understanding was that functions work by pass-by-reference, therefore I am basically sending out the address of the element of the array/argument I am concerned with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the dummy argument of `F` is declared like

```
real(kind=8), intent(in) :: B(1, 10)
```

we open ourselves up to something called *sequence association*.<sup>1</sup>

In this case the subroutine reference

```
call F(B(1, 10*i - 9))
```

does work on that given element of `B` and the following nine elements. In that sense, you are "passing the address of the element". Strictly, though, you are passing a sequence of ten elements to the subroutine, *not* an address. (The compiler will likely implement this as a pass-by-reference, but there is a difference.<sup>2</sup>)

In the subroutine reference

```
call F(A)
```

you are referencing the whole array `A`. There is still a ten element sequence, this time built from the first element of `A`. Again, this is *almost* like passing the address of that first element.

Where you are going wrong, however, is in thinking that

```
A(1, 1) = B(1, 10*i - 9)
```

is working towards what you want. It isn't.

This assignment is copying one element from `B` to the first element of `A`. That's really a copy. It's a brand new value at a brand new address. There's no implied copy of any other element of `B` to any other element of `A`.

You could use a pointer array `A` with pointer assignment to a section of `B`, but that's different and in this case quite unnecessary (so I won't by default show). Or a full array section copy of `B` to the whole array `A`, but again that's different.

Finally, don't forget `F(B(1,10*i-9:10*i))`.

---

<sup>1</sup> See other questions and answers here; also applies to assumed-size arrays like `real B(1,*)`.

<sup>2</sup> You'll see this difference if you have a compiler happy to check that lengths of the element sequences match. As a naive passing of an address, you can supply a shorter sequence than required and then run over that in the subroutine; as a true sequence, a compiler can warn you that it's too short.

Comment: This cleared my doubts. Thanks a lot!